# Linux process and threads scheduling

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, scheduling

I'm playing around with linux scheduling with sched.h and bump into some questions.

From what I know, Linux scheduler do not treat threads and processes differently when scheduling. Threads are just like process which shares common resources.

Ok, Say I have Process-A and it is set to CPU core 0 and SCHED_FIFO property is set; which will runs until another higher priority tasks kicks in. If Process-A creates a new thread, will the thread inherit the same property? (i.e. be bind to CPU 0 with SCHED_FIFO properties or will it be DEFAULT?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually test this with a simple program, but from various man pages:

[sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity):

> A child created via fork(2) inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask.
>   The affinity mask is preserved across an execve(2).

[pthread_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> The new thread inherits copies of the calling thread's capability sets
>   (see
>          capabilities(7)) and CPU affinity mask (see sched_setaffinity(2)).

[sched_setscheduler](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html):

> Child processes inherit the scheduling policy and parameters across a
>   fork(2).
>          The scheduling policy and parameters are preserved across execve(2).